# Two random variables are independent if all continuous and bounded transformations are uncorrelated.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification, independence

Here's a statement I've come across multiple times but have never seen a proof of:

> Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, if for all continuous and bounded funtions $f, g: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ it holds that 
>   $$E[f(X)g(Y)]=E[f(X)]E[g(Y)].\tag{1}$$

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/474218/451957) answer but I'm not sure that I'm filling in the details correctly:

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ satisfy the condition in $(1).$ We want to show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Since the closed intervals generate the Borel sigma algebra, it suffices to show that 
$$P(X\in I_1, Y\in I_2)=P(X\in I_1)P(Y\in I_2)$$
for all closed intervals $I_1, I_2\subset\mathbb R.$ Given two such intervals let $f_n, g_n\ge0$ be sequences of continuous and bounded functions with
$$f_n(\cdot)\uparrow 1(\cdot\in I_1), \quad g_n(\cdot)\uparrow 1(\cdot\in I_2). \tag{2}$$

Then
\begin{align*}
P(X\in I_1, Y\in I_2) &= E[1(X\in I_1, Y\in I_2)]\\
&= E[1(X\in I_1)1(Y\in I_2)]\\
&= E[\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(X)\lim_{m\to\infty}g_m(Y)]\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}E[f_n(X)\lim_{m\to\infty}g_m(Y)]\quad \text{(by monotone convergence)}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}E[f_n(X)g_m(Y)]\quad \text{(by m.c.)}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}E[f_n(X)]E[g_m(Y)]\quad \text{(by assumption)}\\
&= E[1(X\in I_1)]E[1(Y\in I_2)]\quad \text{(by m.c.)}\\
&=P(X\in I_1)P(Y\in I_2),\\
\end{align*}
hence the claim.

**Question: Is my above proof correct?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot take closed intervals in this argument.  The argument works if you take open intervals.

Comment: Is that because otherwise I would not be able to find $f_n$ and $g_n$ with
$$f_n(\cdot)\uparrow 1(\cdot\in I_1), \quad g_n(\cdot)\uparrow 1(\cdot\in I_2)?$$

Comment: Yes, you can do this for open intervals but not for closed intervals.